# Populate li elements with values from array

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, arrays

I would like to loop through `var array = ["one", "two"];` to different list items. So my output should be:

`<li>Number one</li>`

`<li>Number two</li>`

So far, my output is:

`<li>Number onetwo</li>`

`<li>Number onetwo</li>`

EDIT:

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var a = "<?php echo $counter; ?>";
                //jQuery("#menu-item-2215 a").not('.sub-menu li a').append(' ('+a+')');

                jQuery.each(a, function() {
                    jQuery("#menu-audio a").not('.sub-menu li a').append(' ('+a+')');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: And how do you get this output? Your code is?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var a = "<?php echo $counter; ?>";
     //jQuery("#menu-item-2215 a").not('.sub-menu li a').append(' ('+a+')');
     
     jQuery.each(a, function() {
      jQuery("#menu-audio a").not('.sub-menu li a').append(' ('+a+')');
     });
    });
   </script>`

Comment: @user1526570 Please update the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ7Dp/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id='menu'><li></li><li></li> </ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var array = ["one", "two"];

$('ul#menu li').append(function(index){
    $(this).text('Number '+array[index]);
});
```

Comment: If you change it to `$('#menu li').append....` it will be like what my problem is..

Comment: do you mean you hava `<ul id='menu'><li></li> <li></li> </ul> `like this and you want to put every element in those li ?

Comment: Yes. But it has to be **one is to one** pairing.